# Probability of Roulette on a Split and on Red comparison

Tags: probability

In roulette, the bet on a “split” pays 17 to 1 and there are 2 chances in 38 to win. The bet on “red” pays 1 to 1 and there are 18 chances in 38 to win. Compare the following two strategies:

A: bet $\$1: 200$ times (independently) on a split

B: bet $\$1: 200$ times independently on red

In what follows, “making more than $\$x$” means having a net gain of more than $\$x$; “losing more than $\$x$” means having a net gain of less than $-\$x$.

Pick all that are correct.

a) The chance of coming out ahead is greater with strategy A than with strategy B

b) The chance of making more than $\$20$ is greater with strategy A than with strategy B.

c) The chance of losing more than $\$20$ is greater with strategy A than with strategy 
B.

Let $X_1$; $X_2$; .....$X_n$ be independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables, and let $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + .... + X_n$. Then:

$E(S\cap A)=nE(X_1)= 200((\frac{2}{38})(\$17)-(\frac{36}{38}))=
200(\frac{34-36}{38})=-\frac{400}{38}=-10.52$

$E(S\cap B)=200E(X_2)= 200*((\frac{18}{38})(\$1)-(\frac{20}{38}))=
200((18-20)/38)=-400/38=-10.52$